# Assign aggregate result to the entity property not pulling all subquery rows

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a Comment and Votes related to the comment.

```
[Table("QAComment")]
public class QaComment : IEntity
{
    [Key, Column("QACommentID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<QaCommentVote> Votes { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int OverallVote { get; set; }
}

[Table("QACommentVote")]
public class QaCommentVote : IEntity
{
    [Key, Column("QACommentVoteID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QAComment")]
    public int QaCommentId { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual QaComment QaComment { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get comments with the sum of their votes, *not pulling all votes to the application*.
The ways I can see to achive this:
1. Make a database view for Commment and calc votes sum in there.
Cons: dont wanna make extra-views
2. Via LINQ:

```
var comments =
    Set<QaComment>()
        .Select(c => new QaComment() {/* assign every property once again and calc OverallVote */});
```

Cons: don't like to assign allproperties once again.
Is there a better way devoid of that cons?

**UPDATE**
This is what I want as a result of LINQ:

```
SELECT 
    qac.*, 
    (SELECT SUM(v.Value)
     FROM QACommentVote v 
     WHERE v.QACommentID = qac.QACommentID) as OverallVote
FROM QAComment qac
```

Comment: You can use AutoMapper for these kinds of aggregations. All you need is a class that will contain your projection from `QaComment`, let's say `QaCommentInfo`. If `QaCommentInfo` a property `VotesCount`, AutoMapper will create a query including the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `QaComment` and the sum you're looking for separately as anonymous type and merge them into one object using LINQ to Objects:

```
var comments
    = Set<QaComment>()
      .Select(c => new { c, sum = c.Votes.Sum(v => v.Value))
      .AsEnumerable() // to make next query execute as LINQ to Objects query
      .Select(x => { x.c.OverallVote = x.sum; return x.c; })
      .ToList();
```

But to make point clear: I haven't tested that :)

Comment: thanks, a good idea. Do you think this one "Select(x => { x.c.OverallVote = x.sum; return x.c; })" will not work over pure IQueryable? Ok, will checkit...

Comment: No, I think it won't. First of all, because compiler will not be able to transform that into Expression. Lambda can be only transformed to Expression by compiled when it's single line (not uses `{`/`}`) and you have to provide `Expression` as `IQueryable` parameter. But even if it could, I don't think there is an SQL that could be generated from such an Expression.

Comment: I think I'd prefere to make it as extension method because I need to use this code in many places in my app. If no better answers will appear, I'll accept this one. Upvoting now.

Comment: Didnt test yet, a bit later. Please take a look at my update, that is what I want to have as a LINQ result.

Comment: Found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553849/sql-subquery-result-in-linq-and-entity-framework-code-first Looks like there is no way to accomplish it like i want to..